# Guidance in regards to System.IFormatProvider?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a bank management system in C# for an assignment. We were tasked with creating a void function to execute the withdrawal of the funds of specific accounts. Each account has a name associated with it and an amount of funds assigned. The issue is that I've gotten stuck on the whole withdraw part. The problem that has cropped up is the "Cannot convert decimal to System.IFormatProvider?" or CS1501 depending on what I put in. I've gotten stuck on this, so I'd appreciate some perspective. The issues crop up on Execute(). Code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bank_Transaction
{
    public class WithdrawTransaction
    {
        //Instance Variables
        public Account _account; public decimal _amount; bool _executed; bool _success; bool _reversed;

    //Methods
    public WithdrawTransaction(Account account, decimal amount)
        {
            this._account = account;
            this._amount = amount;
        }
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("$" + _amount + " was just withdrawn from " + _account);
        }
        public void Execute() //<- This is where the error is
        {
        decimal newaccount = IConvertible.ToDecimal(_account, _amount);
        _executed = true;

            if (_amount > newaccount)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Insufficient funds");
            }
            else if (_success == true)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The withdrawal has already gone through. You cannot withdraw again.");
            }
            else
            {
                _success = true;
                Console.WriteLine("After the withdrawal operation, this account was left with : $" + _account + ".");
            }
```

Here's the code for Account:

```
public Account(String name, Decimal balance)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? IConvertible.ToDecimal has a different signature, but it doesn't even seem to be applicable here.

Comment: If your Account class has a member to track current balance, I suspect you need something as simple as `account.Balance = account.Balance - amount;`, without going into concurency handling etc

Comment: @shree.pat18 I'm trying to withdraw funds from a specific account. At this point, that's just a hail Mary to see if it would work. I have done that previously, however we're being asked to implement different transaction classes.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what `decimal newaccount = IConvertible.ToDecimal(_account, _amount);` was *meant* to achieve. Why would you be passing an `Account` (which by the way we have no idea of the definition of) to a method called `ToDecimal`? Why would you also be passing `_amount` to this, and then later comparing `newaccount` to `_amount`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the original train of thinking was that since I can't subtract _amount from _account, due to the fact that they're not the same, that I'd turn _account into a decimal (which upon further review makes no sense) and get my result that way. I've discarded newaccount in my program already. Let me update to show what Account is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.